# How can I get this form and button to resize correctly in a responsive design?

Tags: css, widget, wordpress, responsive-design

I am trying to create a customized widget that includes a background image with a text entry form and a button. The wordpress theme I am using is a responsive design built on Twitter Bootstrap. When resizing the browser the form and button are not resizing with the background image. Can anyone help me get this working correctly? You can view the widget at the very bottom of the side bar on the right side of the page on the [live site](http://noahsdad.com/).

Thanks.

```
<form style="-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;padding: 3px;text-align: center;background: url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/noahs-dad-side-bar.jpg) no-repeat center;
padding: 30% 0;" action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=noahsdad', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">
    <p>
        <input type="text" style="width:170px;height:18px;margin-bottom:-110px;margin-left:-125px;" name="email" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your email address';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your email address') {this.value = '';}" value="Enter your email address"/>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" value="noahsdad" name="uri"/><input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
    <input type="submit"  style="margin-bottom:-134px;margin-left:-220px;" value="Subscribe" />
```

Here is my styles.css (this is a child theme)

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Import Standard Styles */

@import url( '../standard3/style.css' );

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Customizations */
#disqus_thread {
    clear: both!important;
    background: white;
    background: white;
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0,transparent 0 0 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.dsq-comment-text p
{
color: black;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 18px;
}



.widget .signupForm {
    /* Box always has colour, pic always on right */
    background-color: #06d0d2;
    background-image: url(http://noahsdad.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/noahs-dad-side-bar.jpg);
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /* height ensures full pic is shown  */
    height: 243px;    

    /* allow us to position contents */
    position: relative;
}

/* Absolutely position the form within the widget */
.widget .signupForm form {
 position: absolute;
 right: 160px;  
 bottom: 70px;
}

.widget .signupForm form input {
 display: block;
}


//* now just resize the widget box and move the form */

    .widget .signupForm {
        width: 300px; 
        height: 240px;
        background-size: 100%;    
    }

    .widget .signupForm form {
        right: 120px;   
        bottom: 50px;
    }
}

/* adjust slightly for larger sizes */
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
    .widget .signupForm {
        width: 343px; 
        height: 275px;
        background-size: 100%;    
    }

    .widget form .signupForm {
        right: 160px;   
        bottom: 70px;
    }
}​


/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Media Queries */

/* Smartphones */
@media (max-width: 480px) {

}

/* Tablet and Mobile */
@media (max-width: 979px) { 

}

/* Mobile to Tablet */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

}


/* Landscape Tablets */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {

}

/* Desktop */
@media (min-width: 980px) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're approaching the positioning of the form incorrectly. With a widget like that, you're better off declaring a fixed size to the widget, and then positioning the form inside it using absolutely relative positioning. Then you can change the box size and form position for each breakpoint.

Here's a fiddle that does what you'd like, but in a cleaner way.

** UPDATED FIDDLE **
http://jsfiddle.net/andrewheins/9PrG2/5/

Your son is awesome, by the way.

Comment: thanks so much for the kind words about our son. I really appreciate that. :)  And thanks for helping me, I'm learning (and still have a lot to learn!) Would I stil put the code into a text widget?

Comment: Hold on, I lost some changes along the way. Yes, you'd still do a custom widget

Comment: Ok, I've updated the fiddle. Take a look at it again. I'm not going to give you cut and paste code, but you should be able to tell how I'm moving the form within the box at each breakpoint. You can change the code within the fiddle to see how it reacts and learn how it's working.

The technique is called absolutely relative positioning, and you can read more about it here: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: thanks so much. I've noticed that the updated one puts a big black box above the image now. Is this correct?

Comment: Ok, I have the widget up and running on the site (on the sidebar, all the way at the bottom) but you'll notice the image doesn't display correctly.Nor does the form / button. How do I get the image to show up (and scale) correctly?

Comment: It looks like you're only declaring the rules once. Remember, you're building a responsive site, you have to declare a set of rules for each breakpoint. You can see in the fiddle that I change the settings at each media query. Same thing for you. You may want to put your rules directly into bootstrap-responsive.css. I'm assuming you know how to use media queries based on how wide your site is. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Comment: I posted my css file. Does it look like I'm doing it incorrect?

Comment: You can see at the bottom of the file all of the media queries. You want to add rules in at relevant breakpoints. You would want to declare your first set of rules in "SmartPhones", add your next set at "Landscape Tablets" and the final set at "Desktop"

Comment: thanks. I ended up having a slash in my CSS that caused some rules not to work, I've corrected it, and it seems to be working now, without having to declare the rules. Does it seem to be working now? If so, how is it working without declaring those rules. Also does it look like I have those breakpoints twice? Under your headings, and the ones in my style sheet? Should I remove one set of the brakes? If that makes sense.

Comment: I still can't this to work correctly. If you resize to where the sidebar goes below the content area things go strange.

Comment: You're fiddle doesn't work at all. Also I don't agree that form elements should have a fixed size. Bootstrap and others have handy solutions for the  use-case above.

Answer (score 0):

find `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {` in bootstrap's css or add it to you own. After that add: `form input {max-width: 10px !important;}`
It will set width of inputs (**all inputs!**) to 10px if screen width is lower than 979px;

It works but it's probably gonna crash your site somewhere so I'd recommend adding some classes/ids to the code of the form and moving all the CSS you now have inline to the stylesheet. It will allow not using the "!important" rule.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm actually using this as a text widget. Will it work adding it directly to the widget? Also this is a child theme I'm using (just in case that makes any difference.)

Comment: I don't remember whether Wordpress allows you to use <style> tags inside the text widget but if it does, just wrap the code around the <style>.....</style>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think I"m understanding your correctly. the @media line wouldn't be in the text widget. Do I just add the <style> tags to the text widget (if that works) and add the max width to it?